# Airflow webserver - OAuth authentication not working when running as system service

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, airflow, systemd

We are running Airflow 2.3.3 on Ubuntu 22.04. Airflow's webserver uses OAuth authentication (and authorization) against Azure AD. This works perfectly fine when invoking Airflow webserver from command line `airflow webserver -D` (as user `ubuntu`).

Now we want to build a systemd service to have the Airflow webserver run automatically upon boot-up of the server. This is our service config file `/lib/systemd/system/airflow-webserver.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target
Before=airflow-scheduler.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow.env
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow webserver -D
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=false
StandardOutput=file:/home/ubuntu/airflow/logs/webserver/systemd-stdout.log
StandardError=file:/home/ubuntu/airflow/logs/webserver/systemd-errout.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`airflow.env` holds these variables:

```
export AIRFLOW_CONFIG=/home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow.cfg
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/ubuntu/airflow
```

When starting the service (`sudo systemctl start airflow-webserver`) the webserver does come up and also shows Airflow's sign-up screen, but when it comes to authentication against Azure AD, we run into some timeout.

I can't figure out the difference between running the webserver from command line vs. running it as a system service. How do I make sure systemd will run the webserver using exactly the same configuration as I do when running it from command line?

Update (2022-10-04):
Output of `sudo journalctl -f -u airflow-webserver` looks all fine - there are a few hints regarding a third-party plugin which we can igonore (because the same messages appear when running the webserver from command line):

```
ubuntu@xxx:~/airflow$ sudo journalctl -f -u airflow-webserver
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: [2022-10-04 10:07:48,734] {init_appbuilder.py:515} INFO - Registering class RedocView on menu
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: [2022-10-04 10:07:48,734] {init_appbuilder.py:515} INFO - Registering class RedocView on menu
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: [2022-10-04 10:07:48,735] {baseviews.py:302} INFO - Registering route /redoc ('GET',)
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: [2022-10-04 10:07:48,735] {baseviews.py:302} INFO - Registering route /redoc ('GET',)
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/plugins_manager.py:256 DeprecationWarning: This decorator is deprecated.
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: In previous versions, all subclasses of BaseOperator must use apply_default decorator for the `default_args` feature to work properly.
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: In current version, it is optional. The decorator is applied automatically using the metaclass.
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py:614 DeprecationWarning: The provider airflow-provider-vaultspeed uses `hook-class-names` property in provider-info and has no `connection-types` one. The 'hook-class-names' property has been deprecated in favour of 'connection-types' in Airflow 2.2. Use **both** in case you want to have backwards compatibility with Airflow < 2.2
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: [2022-10-04 10:07:48,780] {providers_manager.py:623} WARNING - The connection_type 'snowflake' has been already registered by provider 'airflow-provider-vaultspeed.'
Oct 04 10:07:48 ip-10-194-84-28 airflow[1508]: [2022-10-04 10:07:48,801] {providers_manager.py:623} WARNING - The connection_type 'snowflake' has been already registered by provider 'airflow-provider-vaultspeed.'
```

Analyzing processes in `htop` I do see some difference (notice the gunicorn sub process holding parameters from airflow.cfg).

Running from command line (authentication works fine)
[image]

Running from systemctl (authentication does not work):
[image]

Comment: Can you please check logs for your service using `journalctl -f -u <srv-name>`

Comment: Hi @NirajNandane - I updated my post with outputs from `journalctl` and `htop`

Comment: You can keep running `journalctl` in one session and try to restart the service in other session, so that all the start up logs gets captured

Comment: finally found a solution  - see below

Comment: Did you above comment help you to find the root cause?

Comment: no, the output given by `journalctl` wouldn't give me any hint as to why airflow wouldn't connect properly to our OAuth service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that even though the service is run as the user specified by `User=` and `Group=`, by default it lacks most environment variables from login shells (e.g. set by `~/.bashrc` or any script in `/etc/profile.d/`).

We finally found this solution allowing to start the service using exactly the same environment variables as when run directly from an interactive shell:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -l -c 'exec "$@"' _ /some/folder/my-script.sh
```

`bash -l` starts a login shell and executes the command provided after `-c`.
I'm not really sure if the `exec` part is really required or if the script path could simply go directly after `-c` - but this solution works fine for us...